# how to filter with two or more combinations in laravel

Tags: laravel

`enter code here`My question about the **combination** filters in laravel by using `eloquent`.

I am trying to filter with a combination of the following:

```
username
Category
Sub_category
started_at
created_at
status
```

I use where conditions but it not working as required.

```
public function filter(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $user = $user->newQuery();

    // Search for a user based on their name.
    if ($request->has('username')) {
        $user->where('name', $request->input('username'));
    }

    // Search for a user based on their Category.
    if ($request->has('Category')) {
        $user->where('Category', $request->input('Category'));
    }

    // Search for a user based on their Sub_category.
    if ($request->has('Sub_category')) {
        $user->where('Sub_category', $request->input('Sub_category'));
    }
 // Search for a user based on their started_at.
    if ($request->has('started_at')) {
        $user->where('started_at', $request->input('started_at'));
    }
 // Search for a user based on their status.
    if ($request->has('status')) {
        $user->where('status', $request->input('status'));
    }


    // Continue for all of the filters.

    // Get the results and return them.
    return $user->get();
}
```

Comment: show ur code here.

Comment: _"I use where conditions but it not working as required."_ Hi there, please provide a [_Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is _really_ difficult to guess what the issue is without looking at the cause.

Answer (score 1):

You should save your where conditions to the $user variable.

```
$user = $user->where($dbField, $request->input($requestParam));
```

For improved readability, I'd suggest using a loop with all of your filtering cases.

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::query();

    $filters = [
        'username' => 'name',
        'Category' => 'Category',
        'Sub_category' => 'Sub_category',
        'started_at' => 'started_at',
        'status' => 'status'
    ];

    foreach ($filters as $requestParam => $dbField){
        if ($request->has($requestParam)) {
            $users = $users->where($dbField, $request->input($requestParam));
        }
    }

    return $users->get();
}
```

Bear in mind `$request->has` does not check whether the parameter value is empty, use `$request->filled` if you wish so.

Answer (score 0):

This is My examle refer this

```
 public function filter(Request $request)
    {
       $q = User::query();
       $email = $request->input('email');
       $username= $request->input('username');

        $q->when($email,function ($query) use ($email){
           $query->where('email',$email);
        });

        $q->when($username,function ($query) use ($username){
           $query->where('username',$username);
        });

       $results = $q->get();
       //code

    }
```